# No bouding boxes create when running my trained model

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, object-detection, object-detection-api

I have tried to train my model using `ssd_mobilenet_v1_coco_11_06_2017` ,`ssd_mobilenet_v1_coco_2018_01_28` and `faster_rcnn_inception_v2_coco_2018_01_28` and did it successfully however when i tried to run `object_detection_tutorial.ipynb` and test my `test_images` all i get is images without bounding boxes, i trained my model using `model_main.py` and also tried `train.py` and i aquired a loss of < 1 in both. i am using `tensorflow = 1.14` and i tried it on `tensorflow = 2.0`. im stuck in this final step. i am positive i create my `tfrecords` correctly. and also when i run the models(`ssd_mobilenet_v1_coco_11_06_2017` ,`ssd_mobilenet_v1_coco_2018_01_28` and `faster_rcnn_inception_v2_coco_2018_01_28`) that i trained them on they worked perfectly, so i suspect that there is something wrong with my model

Answer (score 0):

Did you update the path of your model in the object_detection_tutorial.ipynb file, "tf.saved_model.load" is the API where you have to give the path of your trained model.